# Error con StreamBuilder Bad State No element

Tags: flutter, dart

Este es la clase que gestiona las shared preferences de unas estadisticas de mi app.
De comienzos sin ningun valor guardado (recien instalada) el comportamiento es normal, muestra null en todas. Despues de obtener un Highscore se modifica el null y muestra correctamente el highscore.
Pero si tiene un highscore guardado y cierro la app al volver a iniciarla ya que son shared preferences deberian mantenerse mis scores pero en vez de eso me salta el error de que "Bad State No element".

Ademas tengo uns prints que me muestran que me sale que "No element" pero en mi lista json hay elementos.

```
I/flutter ( 9539): DJBJKD

═╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following StateError was thrown building StreamBuilder<List<Highscore>>(dirty, state:
_StreamBuilderBaseState<List<Highscore>, AsyncSnapshot<List<Highscore>>>#dc7a6):
Bad state: No element
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  StreamBuilder<List<Highscore>>
```

Este es el codigo de la ruta:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:reactions/src/models/highscore.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'package:reactions/src/models/tipos_modos.dart';

class MainHighscores  {
  BehaviorSubject<List<Highscore>> _highscore$;
  BehaviorSubject<List<Highscore>> get highscore$ => _highscore$;

  MainHighscores()  {
    _highscore$ = BehaviorSubject<List<Highscore>>.seeded(
      [
        Highscore(tipo: TiposModos.Test, time: 0),
        Highscore(tipo: TiposModos.Mejorde3, time: 0),
        Highscore(tipo: TiposModos.Mejorde5, time: 0)
      ],
    );
    retrieveHighscore();
  }

  Future checkHighscore(Highscore highscore) async {
    double oldTime = _highscore$.value
        .firstWhere((test) => test.tipo == highscore.tipo)
        .time;
    double newTime = highscore.time;

    if (oldTime > newTime || oldTime <= 0) {
      print("jjgsss");
      var blocList = _highscore$.value;
      blocList.removeWhere((temp) => temp.getTipo == highscore.getTipo);

      SharedPreferences sharedUser = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = highscore.toJson();
      String newHighscoreJson = jsonEncode(tempMap);
      List<String> highscoreJsonList = [];
      print(sharedUser.getStringList('highscores'));
      if (sharedUser.getStringList('highscores') == null) {
        highscoreJsonList.add(newHighscoreJson);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          String unchangedHighscoreJson = jsonEncode(blocList[i].toJson());
          highscoreJsonList.add(unchangedHighscoreJson);
        }
      } else {
        List<String> prefBeforeDecodeList =
            sharedUser.getStringList('highscores');
        List<Highscore> prefList = [];
        for (String jsonHighscore in prefBeforeDecodeList) {
          Map userMap = jsonDecode(jsonHighscore);
          Highscore tempHighscore = Highscore.fromJson(userMap);
          if (tempHighscore.tipo != highscore.tipo) {
            prefList.add(tempHighscore);
          }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          String unchangedHighscoreJson = jsonEncode(prefList[i].toJson());
          highscoreJsonList.add(unchangedHighscoreJson);
        }
        highscoreJsonList.add(newHighscoreJson);
      }
      sharedUser.setStringList('highscores', highscoreJsonList);
      blocList.add(highscore);
      _highscore$.add(blocList);
    }
  }

  Future retrieveHighscore() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedUser = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> jsonList = sharedUser.getStringList('highscores');
    List<Highscore> prefList = [];
    if (jsonList == null) {
      print("hujef");
      return;
    } else {
      print("DJBJKD");
      for (String jsonHighscore in jsonList) {
        Map userMap = jsonDecode(jsonHighscore);
        Highscore tempHighscore = Highscore.fromJson(userMap);
        prefList.add(tempHighscore);
      }
      _highscore$.add(prefList);
    }
  }
}
```

Y esta es la clase Highscore:

```
import 'package:reactions/src/models/tipos_modos.dart';

class Highscore {
  TiposModos tipo;
  double time;

  Highscore({
    this.tipo,
    this.time,
  });

  String get getTipoString => tipo.toString().substring(6);
  double get getTimeinSeconds => time / 1000;
  TiposModos get getTipo => tipo;
  double get getTime => time;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "tipo": this.tipo.toString().substring(6),
      "time": this.time,
    };
  }

  factory Highscore.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    String tipoString = parsedJson['tipo'];
    TiposModos tempTipo;

    if (tipoString == "Test") {
      tempTipo = TiposModos.Test;
    } else if (tipoString == "Mejorde3") {
      tempTipo = TiposModos.Mejorde3;
    } else {
      tempTipo = TiposModos.Mejorde5;
    }

    return Highscore(
      tipo: tempTipo,
      time: parsedJson['time'],
    );
  }
}
```

**EDICION:**
Al parecer pude controlar mas este error y ahora obtengo otro pero mas concreto:

Este es el error:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<List<Highscore>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<List<Highscore>, AsyncSnapshot<List<Highscore>>>#a7cb1):
The getter 'getTimeinSeconds' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: getTimeinSeconds

The relevant error-causing widget was
    StreamBuilder<List<Highscore>>
```

Y este es el codigo modificado hasta ahora:

```
import 'package:fancy_bottom_navigation/fancy_bottom_navigation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:reactions/src/funcions/main_highscores.dart';
import 'package:reactions/src/models/highscore.dart';
import 'package:reactions/src/models/tipos_modos.dart';
import 'package:reactions/src/ui/menus/principal.dart';

class Estadisticas extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EstadisticasState createState() => _EstadisticasState();
}

class _EstadisticasState extends State<Estadisticas> {
      int currentPage = 0;
    GlobalKey bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MainHighscores mainHighscores = Provider.of<MainHighscores>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Material(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: StreamBuilder<List<Highscore>>(
            stream: mainHighscores.highscore$,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Container();
              }else{
              double testHighscore = snapshot.data
                      .firstWhere((test) => test.tipo == TiposModos.Test,orElse: () => null)
                      .getTimeinSeconds;
                      print(testHighscore);
              double mejorde3Highscore = snapshot.data
                      .firstWhere((test) => test.tipo == TiposModos.Mejorde3,orElse: () => null)
                      .getTimeinSeconds;
              double mejorde5Highscore = snapshot.data
                      .firstWhere((test) => test.tipo == TiposModos.Mejorde5,orElse: () => null)
                      .getTimeinSeconds;
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  HighscoreTile(tipo: "Test", time: testHighscore),
                  HighscoreTile(tipo: "Mejor de 3", time: mejorde3Highscore),
                  HighscoreTile(tipo: "Mejor de 5", time: mejorde5Highscore),
                  //Bottom_bar(currentPage),
                ],
              );
            }}),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: FancyBottomNavigation(
        tabs: [
          TabData(
              iconData: Icons.timeline,
              title: "Estadisticas",
              onclick: () {
                final FancyBottomNavigationState fState =
                    bottomNavigationKey.currentState;
                fState.setPage(0);
              }),
          TabData(
              iconData: Icons.flash_on,
              title: "Home",
              onclick: () {
                final FancyBottomNavigationState fState =
                    bottomNavigationKey.currentState;
                fState.setPage(1);
              }),
          TabData(
              iconData: Icons.settings,
              title: "Ajustes",
              onclick: () {
                final FancyBottomNavigationState fState =
                    bottomNavigationKey.currentState;
                fState.setPage(2);
              }),
        ],
        textColor: Colors.black,
        initialSelection: 0,
        inactiveIconColor: Colors.black,
        activeIconColor: Colors.blue,
        circleColor: Colors.black,
        key: bottomNavigationKey,
        onTabChangedListener: (position) {
          if (!mounted) return;
  setState(() {
    // Your state chsetState(() {
            currentPage = position;
            switch (currentPage) {
              
              case 1:
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MenuPrincipal()));
                break;

              
              case 2:

            }
          });
         
  
          
        },
      ),
    );  
  }
    @override
    void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

  }
}

class HighscoreTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String tipo;
  final double time;

  HighscoreTile({Key key, this.tipo, this.time}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xff2b2b2b),
            //color: Colors.black,
            //borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            // Radius.circular(8),
            // ),
            //border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  offset: Offset(0, 0),
                  //blurRadius: 10,
                  spreadRadius: 2),
            ],
          ),
          child: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                (time <= 0 || time==null)
                    ? tipo + ": Null"
                    : tipo + ": " + time.toString() + " secs",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Cómo ya debes saber la solución no va en la pregunta, por favor edita y quitala de ahí y colócala en la zona de respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione cambiando  `String get getTipoString => tipo.toString().substring(6);`
por
`String get getTipoString => tipo.toString().substring(11);`
tanto ahi como por `"tipo": this.tipo.toString().substring(11),`

Dado que con 6 me quedaba odos.Test y eso es lo que guardaba en el Json y al volver a leer el json no coincidia test con odos.test asi que devolvia null.
cambiandolo por 11 quedaba test=test por lo que al coincidir devolvia el valor asociado a ese null.